# SSRS/Report Builder datediff in working days

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I have a calculated field in my report that gives me the number of days between two fields. This is in calendar days though.

=DateDiff("d",Fields!Date_Reported.Value,Fields!EventDate.Value)

I have been asked to include number of working days and I'm struggling!

Is it possible to count the number days between these fields using only working days? eg. Monday to Friday in this case?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=datediff("ww",Fields!Date_Reported.Value,Fields!EventDate.Value, vbMonday)
+datediff("ww",Fields!Date_Reported.Value,Fields!EventDate.Value, vbTuesday)
+datediff("ww",Fields!Date_Reported.Value,Fields!EventDate.Value, vbWednesday)
+datediff("ww",Fields!Date_Reported.Value,Fields!EventDate.Value, vbThursday)
+datediff("ww",Fields!Date_Reported.Value,Fields!EventDate.Value, vbFriday)
```

<sup>The [source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f7c567be-468e-43ed-8248-f13f6f666a7e/datediff-in-expression-excluding-weekendsholidays?forum=sqlreportingservices)</sup>

Comment: That's great, it seems to be working perfectly. thank you very much Alex.